# Disable one link in dropdown in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I want to disable one link from the b-dropdown item in vuejs based on their status.
I want to show both the `values - name`, but i want to disable the name which has status `not complete`

```html
<span v-for="users in value.user">
 <b-dropdown-item
   :key="user.id"
   active="active"
 >
   <span>
     {{ user.name }}
   </span>
 </b-dropdown-item>
</span>
```

While i have the arrays of values from `value.user` as this

```js
[
     {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"XXX",
      "status":"complete",
     },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "name":"XXX",
      "status":"not complete",
   }
]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/dropdown#b-dropdown-item)

> Disable the dropdown item by setting the `disabled` prop.

```html
<b-dropdown>
  <b-dropdown-item
    v-for="users in value.user"
    :key="user.id"
    active="active"
    :disabled="user.status === 'not complete'"
  >
    <span>
      {{ user.name }}
    </span>
  </b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>
```